# How do I supress the print of "msys\r\n" in msys bash.exe on windows 10

Tags: bash, msys2

I installed msys on a windows 10 machine so I could get the bash shell.
I want to excecute a command via bash -c "myCommand.sh" and get the value it prints but the bash.exe always prints "msysy\r\n" before any of the output from the command.

This makes it impractical to use it to return strings.

Is there any way to suppress this print ?

Comment: It appears this is only printed when --login is specified. :|

Comment: I haven't seen that happen before.  Does it print "msys" if you run MSYS2 the usual way (e.g. run msys2.exe, mingw32.exe, or mingw64.exe)?  What files do you have in `/etc/profile.d/`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bashrc`, and have you investigated which of those might be printing the message?

Comment: @DavidGrayson  It prints it if the --login flag is specified it doesn't if not It is the latest msys2 as of a few months ago.  I have .bashrc and .bash_profile in my home dir but they don't do it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson  I just checked and nothing in the msys/etc folder profiles profile.d etc echos the string 'msys' as the first thing done. This is the out of the box install of MsysGit + Msys 64 bit on windows 10.